# Adobe Acrobat Pro - Get display value from dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I'm trying to read out both the "export value", and the text value that is displayed to the user of the form in adobe acrobat pro using javascript.

I can't seem to find documentation, or if there is any way to determine the value that is displayed if a value is specified in the "export value" field.

Example:
DropDown with values :
("None", 0) 
("Standard, 1)
("Premium", 2)

Then in my javascript, standard is selected:

```
this.getField("DDL").rawValue //returns undefined
this.getField("DDL").value //returns 1
this.getField("DDL").valueAsString //returns "1"
```

Is there a property that will return "Standard"?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it... the getItemAt method with an additional parameter "bExportValue" of "false" will retrieve the display value for the dropdown at the current value.

```
var field = this.getField("DDL");
var selectedIndex = field.currentValueIndices;
var exportValue = field.getItemAt(selectedIndex); // The field value
var displayValue = field.getItemAt(selectedIndex, false); // Label shown in the UI
console.println(displayValue+": "+exportValue);
```